# read otp from phone and submit to website on desktop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome, web-worker

How can we send OTP received on android to website like paisabazaar.com

How paisabazaar.com works

Login to paisabazaar.com using mobile no
You get an OTP
When you receive OTP a popup is shown (see attached screenshot)

[image]

I have no idea how they are doing this.
Are they are using web workers, firebase?

If they can read my messages for OTP can they read my other messages?

Comment: I believe that's a convenience feature of the phone, nothing to do with paisabazaar - you are logging in on the phone as well, right? When you say "desktop" you don't mean an actual desktop computer?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, i mean an actual desktop computer 
One more point to add, i had logged into paisabazaar on my phone few days back

Comment: and you're saying the browser on your desktop machine read the text message from your phone?

Comment: @JaromandaX When i try to login via desktop using my mobile number when i receive an OTP android shows an popup (see screenshot) if i click submit the OTP is automatically entered on the website on desktop

Comment: maybe it's because you're using chrome on both devices, and you're logged into to the same google account on both chrome's - as to how it's done - hmmm, not sure if it's a chrome thing or a website thing now